Read Write Segregation issue in Spring Boot JPA
I am following Vlad's article on Read Write Segregation . I have an AWS RDS cluster set up with reader and writer instances. Based on the article, I have created the below classes. Reads are going fine to the Reader instance of AWS RDS, but when trying to run insert/update queries , it gives me the below error. Spring Boot 3.1.11
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to bind parameter #3 - [ERROR: cannot assign OIDs during recovery] 

Below class to determine which data source to route the current transaction to :
public class MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TransactionSynchronizationManager
                .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ?
                DatabaseEnvironment.UPDATABLE :
                DatabaseEnvironment.READONLY;
    }
}

The data source configuration class which houses the reader and writer data sources and a facade datasource to switch the connection
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbc.master.url}")
    private String mstUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.master.username}")
    private String mstUsername;

    @Value("${jdbc.master.password}")
    private String mstPassword;

    @Value("${jdbc.slave.url}")
    private String slaveUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.slave.username}")
    private String slaveUsername;

    @Value("${jdbc.slave.password}")
    private String slavePassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource masterSlaveRoutingDataSource = new MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(DatabaseEnvironment.UPDATABLE, masterDataSource());
        targetDataSources.put(DatabaseEnvironment.READONLY, slaveDataSource());
        masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        // Set as all transaction point to master
        masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource());
        return masterSlaveRoutingDataSource;
    }

    public DataSource slaveDataSource() {

        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(slaveUrl);
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(slaveUsername);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(slavePassword);
        hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
        int cpuCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(cpuCores*4);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(mstUrl);
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(mstUsername);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(mstPassword);
        hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
        int cpuCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(cpuCores*4);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }
}

Enum
public enum DatabaseEnvironment {
    UPDATABLE,
    READONLY
}

Application YML file to store the properties
jdbc:
  master:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test
    username: test
    password: test
  slave:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://xxx-ro.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test
    username: test
    password: test
spring:
 jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: false
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
        event:
          merge:
            entity_copy_observer: allow
        connection:
          provider_disables_autocommit: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update


your configuration actually routes DML queries to readonly replica: isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ? DatabaseEnvironment.UPDATABLE : DatabaseEnvironment.READONLY
